# Fetching data from mysql database in the VIEW structure of Zend 2.2?

Tags: php, eclipse, mysqli, phpmyadmin, zend-framework2

I am a newbie in php+Zend programming, so need your valuable advice.
1. I have a table in mysql (phpmyadmin), the attributes in the table are ~ user_id, expense_id, date month, year, expense. 
2. I have .phtml file (index.phtml) in the View folder (Zend 2.2). It is accessed by indexAction() in the Controller page. Code:

> return viewmodel ( return array=>(
>   'years'=>$this->getExpenseTable()->fetchAll($user_id); )),

[sorry if it's not in the proper format]. This function is meant to return all the values from the db, when I put it into a table with foreach. The code in index.phtml is below:

> escapeHtml($expense->expense);?>  .....and so on......

Now my problem is: 
a) I cannot use the variable 'years' in another table with another foreach loop in the same index.phtml file. it says, "this is a forward-only result-set." I tried implementing unset() and rewind(), both did not work. 
b) I want to take **unique** value of the attribute 'year' from the table (as table header you might think) and put the summation of expenses under each year.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple questions which should perhaps be wrapped in multiple questions, but anyhow, here it goes:

*Iterate multiple times over a single resultset*:

Some drivers allow buffering. The value of `$years` is a Zend ResultSet object. You can call `$years->buffer()` before you loop to enable the internal buffer so you can iterate twice:

```
// $set is ResultSet
$set->buffer();

foreach ($set as $result) {} // first time
foreach ($set as $result) {} // second time
```

*Extract the year*:

You can use simple view logic for that:

```
// example resultset
$result = array(
  array('year' => '2012', 'value' => 'foo'),
  array('year' => '2012', 'value' => 'bar'),
  array('year' => '2013', 'value' => 'baz'),
);

// store year for check
$year = null;
foreach ($result as $item) {
    if ($item['year']) !== $year) {
        $year = $item['year'];
        echo $year;
    }

    echo $item['value'];
}
```

Comment: Hi..I tried this solution, but whenever I run this code, it says "buffer() is a protected property, and it cannot be accessed." :( Is there any remedy?